# GDB `command` on `rbreak`

Tags: debugging, gdb

In GDB, it's possible to execute a series of commands when hitting a breakpoint, like this

```bash
(gdb) break Foo
(gdb) command
Type commands for breakpoint(s) 3, one per line.
End with a line saying just "end".
>print $sp
>continue
>end
(gdb)
```

How would I get these commands to execute on [regex breakpoints](https://www.zeuthen.desy.de/dv/documentation/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/Set-Breaks.html#:%7E:text=rbreak%20regex) instead of just manually specified ones?

Comment: `commands` without arguments already does that. The [docu](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html) says ` If the most recent breakpoints were set with a single command, then the commands will apply to all the breakpoints set by that command. This applies to breakpoints set by rbreak, and also applies when a single break command creates multiple breakpoints`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve it. I would something working whether or not the breakpoints are currently loaded. With `command` and a single pending breakpoint it works fine whether or not the breakpoints are currently in the file, while `commands` and `rbreak` only fires on those already seen.